# Вложенность селектора

Tags: html, css

```css
.services-shop .services-shop-about p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<section class="services-shop container">
  <div class="services-shop-about">
    <h2>Сервисы</h2>
    <p>
      Хороший интернет-магазин отличается от плохого не только ценами! Мы стараемся изо всех сил, чтобы сделать ваши покупки приятными.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="services-shop-bottom">
    <ul class="services-shop-menu">
      <li class="services-shop-menu-active">Доставка</li>
      <li>Гарантия</li>
      <li>Кредит</li>
    </ul>
    <section class="delivery-service">
      <h3>Доставка</h3>
      <p>
        Мы с удовольствием доставим ваш товар прямо<br> к вашему подъезду совершенно бесплатно! Ведь мы неплохо заработаем,<br> поднимая его на ваш этаж!
      </p>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>
```

Как в таком случае сделать вложенность менее трёх, т.е два? Если убрать .services-shop, то параметры не применяются. Подскажите, где и что нужно искать. Большое спасибо!

Comment: А зачем вам уменьшать уровень вложенности?